# C# how to get an array of int* from unmanaged C++

Tags: c#, c++, marshalling

On the unmanaged side I have `short* m_pLevels[4]`, I need to get this array of pointers to the C# side so I can then use each point to copy from the unmanaged side to a managed array.
How do I get an array of `short*` to C# and would that array be an array of `IntPtr` ?

Comment: There are a variety of different ways to marshal data, but we need more info. Do you have sample code?

Comment: What are the pointers pointing to?

Comment: @John V - the example is in the question. On the unmanaged side the is an array of pointers to shorts. The shorts being pointed to could be a few dozen to thousands. I am OK, I think on get the data pointed to by the short pointers to the managed side. I am just not quite sure how to get an array of pointers to the managed and use them as pointers.

Comment: What we need to see is the declaration of the C++ function you're intending call, and the portion of the C# function where you are trying to call that function. See my answer for an example.

Answer (score 2):

I recomend using **C++/CLI** to communicate between C# (managed) and C++ (native).
In the examples below I used the simplest case where the native data is simply 1 binary buffer.
You can adapt it to pass any form of native data.

**You can take one of these 2 approaches:**

1. The **most efficient way** is to pass the unmanaged data to C# and use it as is.
   You will have to use an `unsafe` methods to handle raw pointers.
   It's efficient but more risky.
   An example for an unsafe C# method getting a native buffer:

   ```
   unsafe void HandleNativeData(sbyte* pData, int dataLen)
   {
       // ...
   }
   ```
2. The **safest way** is to marshal the unmanaged memory to managed one.
   If for example you have a C# or C++/CLI method that got a raw pointer from C++ (like in approach 1), you can do the following:

   ```
   unsafe void HandleNativeData(sbyte* pData, int dataLen)
   {
        byte[] DataManagedBuf = new byte[dataLen];
        Marshal.Copy((IntPtr)pData, DataManagedBuf, 0, dataLen);

        // At this point DataManagedBuf is a proper managed buffer,
        //  containing the data that was passed from native C++.
   }
   ```

Comment: thanks I agree with your solution for getting the shorts across into an array on the managed side. What I am stuck on, is trying to bring an array of short pointers to the managed side so I can use the pointes to marshal the data across.

Comment: That's exactly what his examples do. If you use c++ CLI then you can just call a method in the c++ code like you normally would.

Comment: @John V - yes, you are correct, it works fine.  What I was struggling with was passing an array of short pointers from the unmanaged side to the managed side. I figured that out and the Marshal.Copy was easy.

Answer (score 1):

PInvoke is also an option:

```
// this function pre-supposes that everyone knows there are always
// exactly 4 buffers of data. that's pretty rare for IRL interop.
// normally you'd use a struct with fixed length arrays, but the 
// question explicitly states short*[].

[DllImport("UnmanagedCode.dll", EntryPoint = "NameOfUnmanagedCodeFunction"]
private static extern void GetUnmanagedBuffers(IntPtr[] shortPtrs, int[] lengths);

// this function will call the unmanaged function and then
// marshal over the pointers into managed arrays
public List<short[]> GetBuffers()
{
    var managedArrays = new List<short[]>(4);

    // the unmanaged DLL fills in the buffer addresses for us
    var shortPtrs = new IntPtr[4];

    // and the lengths of each buffer
    var lengths = new int[4];
    
    GetUnmanagedBuffers(shortPtrs, lengths);

    // input validation/exception handling omitted for brevity    

    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
    {
         var length = bufferLengths[i];

         // create the array and add it to the return values
         managedArrays.Add(new short[length]);

         // the overload of Marshal.Copy that works with int16[]
         Marshal.Copy(bufferPtrs[i],    //source pointer
                      managedArrays[i], //destination array
                      0,                //starting index into dest
                      length)           //number of int16 to copy
    }

    // often you'd see another PInvoke here telling the unmanaged 
    // code that you're done with the buffers so they can be freed.
    return managedArrays;
}
```